# How to draw a dodecahedron with each face modified to a pentagram?

Tags: graphics3d, polyhedra, geometry

I'd like to draw a dodecahedron with each face carved on the sides so it becomes a pentagram.  I wonder how to start to do this kind of task in the Wolfram Language?

**Edit:**

The result should still be a completely enclosed polyhedron; i.e., the carved out parts should be connected by newly added faces.  I don't want the result to have holes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution from @chuy looks really nice. Although I think that it was a little bit of work around because it's a visualization only, but the defined structure doesn't really represent the carved dodecahedron. Here is my approach of carving a dodecahedron pumpkin into pentagrams.

First we define a function that makes a pentagram from a pentagon.

```
tau = (2 Sqrt[5])/(5 + Sqrt[5]);
pentagram[pts_] := 
  Riffle[pts, #] &@(pts[[# + 1]]*tau + (1 - tau)*
        pts[[1 + Mod[# + 2, 5]]] & /@ Range[0, 4, 1]);
```

Then we apply this function to all faces of dodecahedron.

```
ind = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "FaceIndices"];
vert = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"];
polyVerts = Reverse@*pentagram /@ (vert[[#]] & /@ ind);
```

Note the `Reverse`, it doesn't have to be there, since it just changes the orientation of the pentagram, but it's required to avoid weird artifacts while rendering, see more [discussion here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85029/how-to-make-sure-polygon-is-drawn-flat-in-3d).

Now we need to create inner faces of our pumpkin.

```
pairs = Partition[#, 2] &@Riffle[#, #*85/100] &@polyVerts;
```

`pairs` contain the outer face and inner face. The last thing to do is create wedges that will connect inner faces with outer faces.

```
wedges[face_] := (Permute[#, Cycles[{{4, 3}}]] &@Flatten[#, 1] &@
        face[[1 ;; -1, #, 1 ;; -1]]) & /@ 
     Partition[#, 2, 1] &@(Range[1, 10]~Join~{1});
```

Now we need to draw all our polygons: faces and wedges:

```
Graphics3D[
 Join[{EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}],  Orange}, 
  Polygon /@ Join[wedges[#], #] & /@ pairs], Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Carved pumpkin]

**Edit:** It has been requested to have no holes in the resulting polyhedron.
So no more pumpkin carving.

Let's make a list of all added vertices and include the original pentagon vertex indices that produced these additional concave vertices.

```
pairList[l_, r_] := Partition[#, 2] &@Riffle[#, RotateLeft[#, r]] &@ l;

concVerts[vert_, face_] := 
  Partition[#, 2] &@
   Riffle[Sort /@ pairList[face, 1], 
    vert[[First[#]]]*tau + (1 - tau)*vert[[Last[#]]] & /@ 
     pairList[face, 2]];
concave = Flatten[#, 1] &@(concVerts[vert, #] & /@ ind);
```

Now we will fill holes with triangles, every triangle has two concave vertices and one original pentagon vertex.

```
triang[vert_, up_, edge_, 
   conc_] := {vert[[#[[1, up]]]], #[[2]], #[[4]]} &@Flatten[#, 1] &@ 
   Select[concave, #[[1]] == edge &];

edges = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Edges"];

tri = Flatten[#, 1] &@
   Table[triang[vert, i, edges[[j]], concave], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 
     Length@edges}];
Graphics3D[
 Join[Polygon /@ tri, {EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}],  Orange}, 
  Polygon /@ polyVerts], Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Carved dodecahedron]

[Full code on Wolfram Cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/725f7076-e513-4ff2-b98f-61640416f8e9)

Comment: Only black cow was able to get what I exactly wanted.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried to run this but it seems `edges` is undefined. Is there some more code? Thanks.

Comment: @shirha I added the missing definition of `edges`

Comment: Got it off the cloud. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

First, I defined `dd` as follows:

```
dd = Entity["Polyhedron", "Dodecahedron"]
(* regular dodecahedron *)
```

Probing the properties of this `Entity` object, I can extract the vertex coordinates (I used `Short` here to truncate the output):

```
dd["VertexCoordinates"]//Short
(* {{-Sqrt[1+2/Sqrt[5]],0,Root[1-20 #1^2+80 #1^4&,3]},<<19>>} *)
```

Now, I can use the property `"FaceIndices"` to see which coordinate corresponds to which point in the face of each side.

```
dd["FaceIndices"]
(* {{15, 10, 9, 14, 1}, {2, 6, 12, 11, 5}, {5, 11, 7, 3, 19}, 
    {11, 12, 8, 16, 7}, {12, 6, 20, 4, 8}, {6, 2, 13, 18, 20}, 
    {2, 5, 19, 17, 13}, {4, 20, 18, 10, 15}, {18, 13, 17, 9, 10}, 
    {17, 19, 3, 14, 9}, {3, 7, 16, 1, 14}, {16, 8, 4, 15, 1}} *)
```

It turns out that the order given is (not surprisingly) for a pentagon rather than a pentagram...

```
Graphics3D[Arrow[dd["VertexCoordinates"][[dd["FaceIndices"][[1]]]]]]
```

[image]

But a bit of shuffling can correct that.  I used [`Permute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permute.html) and [`PermutationCycles`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PermutationCycles.html).

Finally, I want to close the loop and connect the last vertex to the first one (for each face).  To do this, I used [`BSplineCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineCurve.html) with the option [`SplineClosed -> True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SplineClosed.html).

All together:

```
pents = BSplineCurve[Permute[#, PermutationCycles[{1, 3, 5, 2, 4}]], 
     SplineDegree -> 1, 
     SplineClosed -> True] & /@ (Part[dd["VertexCoordinates"], #] & /@ 
     dd["FaceIndices"]);

Graphics3D[{Thick, White, pents, Purple, Opacity[0.75], dd["Faces"]}]
```

[image]

And if desired, rather than using `BSplineCurve`, you can use `Polygon` to also get a nice effect:

```
pents2 = Polygon[
     Permute[#, 
      PermutationCycles[{1, 3, 5, 2, 4}]]] & /@ (Part[
       dd["VertexCoordinates"], #] & /@ dd["FaceIndices"]);

Graphics3D[{Thick, White, pents2}, Background -> Black, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
gr = Show[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron"], Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 400];

gr2 = gr /. Polygon[x_] :> Polygon[#[[{1, 3, 5, 2, 4}]] & /@ x];

Row[{gr, gr2}]
```

[image]

Comment: But I actually want the each four neighbouring edges currently enclosing a halo to be connected by a smooth added new face.  Also, each pentagram should not have a halo center.

Answer (score 5):

You can make your own satan-worshiping dodecahedron by using texture. The following is more-or-less based on a [Neat Example in the `Texture` documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture.html).

First, download your favourite evil pentagram image:

```
im = Import["http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/sonicfanchara/images/9/9c/\
Goth-pentagram-devil.gif/revision/latest?cb=20131018174814"];
```

[image: pentagram]

Then work out the vertex coordinates of a pentagon, normalised so that the centre is in the right place (depending on your choice of image you may need to rotate appropriately - here 3 π/2). Use `t` as a scaling parameter:

```
(Sqrt[2] Normalize[ImageDimensions[im]] + t {Re@#, Im@#}) & /@
 (E^(I (2 # π + 3 π/2)/5) &@ Range[5]))/2
```

Now plug all this into a manipulate so that you have some control over how much goat there is in your dodecahedron:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Texture[im], 
   FaceForm[
    Red], (Append[#1, {VertexTextureCoordinates -> ( ( 
              Sqrt[2] Normalize[ImageDimensions[im]] +t { Re@#,  Im@#}) & /@
              (E^(I (2 # π + 3 π/2)/5) & @ Range[5]))/2}] &) /@ 
    Flatten @ Normal @ PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"] }, 
  Background -> Gray], {t, .2, 1}]
```

[image: textured polyhedron]

Finally, why not start a metal band? If short of name ideas, let Mathematica decide for you:

```
"The " <> RandomChoice[WordData[All, "Adjective"]] <> " " <> 
 RandomChoice[WordData[All, "Noun"]]

The petite American Staffordshire terrier
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit late, but I only recently learned of the `"AdjacentFaceIndices"` property in `PolyhedronData[]`, and this is what led me to figure out how to cleanly deal with generating the required triangles.

First, generate the extra pentagram points from the original dodecahedron's vertices:

```
np = First @ Normal[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"]] /. Polygon[pts_] :>
     RootReduce[ScalingTransform[ConstantArray[1 - Tan[π/Length[pts]]^2, 3], Mean[pts]] @
                ListCorrelate[{{1}, {1}}/2, pts, 1]];
```

Notice that I did not use `N[]`; I wanted to keep the coordinates exact. The appropriate scaling factor was derived through a little bit of trigonometry.

Generate the corresponding indices:

```
nidx = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCount"] + Range[Length[Flatten[np, 1]]];
```

The index arrangement for the star faces can then be generated like this:

```
fid = MapThread[Riffle, {PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "FaceIndices"],
                         Partition[nidx, 5]}];
```

Now, the hard part. The idea here is to use `"AdjacentFaceIndices"` to retrieve the corresponding entries in `fid`, and match them up with entries from `"EdgeIndices"`. Some shuffling should then yield the indices for the triangular faces.

```
facs = Function[{fi, af}, fi[[#]] & /@ af][ArrayPad[#, {0, 1}, "Periodic"] & /@ fid, 
                PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "AdjacentFaceIndices"]];

(* triangle indices *)
tris = Flatten[MapThread[Function[{facs, edg}, 
                                  Through[{Most, Composition[Reverse, Rest]}[
                                          Insert[#[[1]], #[[2, 2]], 2]]] &[
               First[SequenceCases[#, # | Reverse[#] & @ Insert[edg, _, 2]]] & /@ facs]],
               {facs, PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "EdgeIndices"]}], 1];
```

Finally, generate the modified dodecahedron:

```
dodstar = GraphicsComplex[Join[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"],
                               Flatten[np, 1]], Polygon[Join[fid, tris]]];

Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Opacity[3/4, ColorData[97, 1]], 
                     Directive[Specularity[3/4, 15], ColorData[97, 2]]],
            dodstar}, 
           Boxed -> False, 
           Lighting -> {{"Ambient", Gray},
                        {"Directional", RGBColor[0.15473514, 0.21284718, 0.29811516], 
                         ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]},
                        {"Directional", RGBColor[0.15473514, 0.21284718, 0.29811516], 
                         ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]},
                        {"Directional", RGBColor[0.15473514, 0.21284718, 0.29811516], 
                         ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}]
```

[image: my stars!]

(The use of `FaceForm[]` was to demonstrate that all the polygons were oriented consistently anticlockwise.)

Comment: P.S. [one of my previous Gravatars](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9W4dh.png) is but a more ornate version of this polyhedron.

Comment: Hi J.M., new user here. How do I ask for someone to look at an old post to see if they can get BlacKow's code to work? The variable `edges` seems to be undefined and I would like to see a working version of his code. I plan on studying your solution as well. It's exactly what I'm trying to do. Thanks if you see this.

Comment: @shirha, you could have just left a comment on his answer asking about it, you know.

Answer (score 4):

```
polyhed = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Polyhedron"];
coords = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"];
lines = Graphics3D[Line[Tuples[coords, 2]]];
Show[polyhed, lines]
```

[image]

This is a bit of a cheat, since it actually draws lines connecting *all* pairs of points on the dodecahedron (take a look at the `lines` object I define in the code);  it's just that the lines that run inside the dodecahedron are hidden.