# How to get the actual Wolfram Language code to draw polyhedra in PolyhedronData?

Tags: curated-data, polyhedra

`PolyhedronData[]` gives a nice collection of polyhedra. And calling `PolyhedronData["DodecahedronIcosahedronCompound", "Image"]` will give you a nice image of a polyhedron entity.  But how does one go about finding the actual Wolfram Language code that will draw this image?  The reason I need this is that I'd like to tweak that with additional options such as colors, textures, lighting etc and produce something I want.

Comment: `PolyhedronData["DodecahedronIcosahedronCompound"]//FullForm`,  you probably need `PolyhedronData["DodecahedronIcosahedronCompound", "Faces"]` though.

Comment: And I just realized that you asked  somewhat similar [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84939/how-to-draw-a-dodecahedron-with-each-face-modified-to-a-pentagram) that has several answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So just for illustration purpose, let's color all Dodecahedron parts orange and Icosahedron part blue.

```
{vert, faceInd} = 
  PolyhedronData[
     "DodecahedronIcosahedronCompound", #] & /@ {"VertexCoordinates", 
    "FaceIndices"};
orange = Polygon /@ (vert[[#]] & /@ # & /@ 
     Select[faceInd, Length[#] == 5 &]);
blue = Polygon /@ (vert[[#]] & /@ # & /@ 
     Select[faceInd, Length[#] == 3 &]);
Graphics3D[{Orange, orange, Blue, blue}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

And for extra fun we can make the Icosahedron spin around.

```
b[t_] := Rotate[blue, t Degree, {0, 0, 1}];
Animate[
 Graphics3D[{Orange, orange, Blue, b[t]}, Boxed -> False], {t, 0, 360,
   10}]
```

[image]